# How do I monitor a directory with Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm doing a directory-monitoring project. I'd to write a bash script that will calculate the md5checksum of a directory, and store that variable for later comparison. This script will have to run by cronjob and will execute a command if said variable doesn't match the earlier set one.

When I run

```
echo -n /path/to/directory | md5sum
```

I'm certain that it is only calculating the md5 of the string "/path/to/directory", and not the directory itself.

Is this possible? If so, how do I then store that variable for later comparison by the next instance of the script?

Comment: Your question might be covered by this similar one: "How can I calculate an md5 checksum of a directory?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657232/how-can-i-calculate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-directory

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475252/bash-script-watch-folder-execute-command

Comment: Have you looked at [incrond](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)?

Comment: I am unable to install additional packages on this server; I would've loved to use something like inotify-wait or the incrond solution. The other solutions I found did not seem to fit what I am trying to achieve. Would it be best to run this via cronjob or in a never-ending loop?

Comment: do you want to calc the md5sum for the data in the File Allocation Table for that directory (or OS equivalant (sp!)) OR for the sum-total of all files (their text, date, etc) in that dir structure?

Comment: I believe the File Allocation Table would be best.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ls /path/to/directory | md5sum`?

*how do I then store that variable for later comparison by the next instance of the script?* 
The easiest solution would be store it in a file.

Comment: But it only covers a structure of a directory, not the files contest (it wasn't clear which one is that was asked for). *ls -l* could be used instead, so files size, permissions and date modified will be taken into an account.

Answer (score 0):

`md5sum` only handles files so you will have to produce a list of filenames. `find` with the  `-type f` parameter is a good way to recursively get the contents of a directory.

If you store the output of md5sum in a file then you can use `md5sum -c` to check which files have changed.