# How to find md5 of .pkg file on mac

Tags: macos, package, md5

I have tried finding md5 of a package on mac using following command:

```
md5 filename.pkg
```

it is giving me this error:

```
filename.pkg is a directory
```

Can somebody help me getting correct `md5` of a package on mac or any pointers to the topic? i have used to find `md5` of `.app` files with the same method and as per my understanding .app is also a directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the checksum of a directory. More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657232/how-can-i-calculate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-directory)