# Different md5sum on same files in local / remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, server, md5sum

I would like to check the md5sum of a list of files I have on my local machine and compare it to the md5sum of the same files I copied on a remote server.

If I check separately in the terminal on each machine :

```
# local
find . -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum
> 5a58015f2abec5bb1ee3e6a003ec4beb  -

# remote
find . -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum
> 5a58015f2abec5bb1ee3e6a003ec4beb  -
```

Now, if I run these commands into a bash script :

```
path_local="path/to/data/"
server_remote="user@ip.adress"
path_remote="path/to/data/"

local_md5sum=$(find ${path_local} -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum)
echo "local_md5sum : ${local_md5sum}"
remote_md5sum=$(ssh ${server_remote} "find ${path_remote} -type f -name '*.fastq.gz' -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum")
echo "remote_md5sum : ${remote_md5sum}"

> local_md5sum : 5a58015f2abec5bb1ee3e6a003ec4beb  -
> remote_md5sum : 4a32580085edf9e49e00c46920517dd1  -
```

The only difference I see in my script is that I use simple quotes for `'*.fastq.gz'` instead of double quotes in my previous command. But I have to or I get `find: paths must precede expression` error.

Why I don't have the same md5sum and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Why did you  `md5sum | md5sum` ???

Comment: Because I have 26 files, with the first md5sum I get a list of 26 md5sum, then I sort this list and I do another md5sum of this list so I can compare just one hash. I found it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657232/how-can-i-calculate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-directory

Comment: So compare all (26 lines) output first!

Comment: Unfortunely, there is no way to try this for us! So we can't see where is the bug... Care about `ssh ... "...'...$1...'..."`  Try to escape $ sign or invert quotes and double quotes.

Comment: Or use syntax: `ssh remote /bin/bash <<-"eosshcmd"` ... split your script in lines and add `eosshcmd` at end... Ensure to use quoted word for not expand variables in command.

Comment: Try: `remote_md5sum=$(ssh ${server_remote} /bin/bash <<< $'find ${path_remote} -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -exec md5sum {} + | awk \047{print $1}\047 | sort | md5sum')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting a quoting problem: on the remote server section you need to scape the `$`, like this: `awk '{print \$1}'`:

Resulting:

```
remote_md5sum=$(ssh ${server_remote} "find ${path_remote} -type f -name '*.fastq.gz' -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print \$1}' | sort | md5sum")
```