# Testing application after migrate to GIT

Tags: git, svn

So my company just decided to move to git from SVN. Basically, we move our SVN repo to new GIT Repo. We've done that. And we also already compared the files from the SVN as our sources and GIT as our target. But our supervisor insist that we need to test each of our migrated application manually.

So here's the detail of our supervisor demand :

1. We migrate the script of our 100 application from development and production to GIT.
2. We will clone the script containing 2 branches, dev and prod on a new server.
3. We will test each applications manually, we will login to the apps, test each modules, etc.

My question is, is this the best practice for testing application migration to GIT? As far as I know, testing GIT is as far as we compare the object from the source repo and target repo. Or I was mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If your supervisor accepts that the same input should produce the same output from your compiler then you need only check that the inputs (the source files) have remained unchanged.

Something like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912975/1281548) would convince me.

Comment: Hi, do you have article regarding that? I mean article about best practice on testing git results.